# Twitter relay/funneling

Tags: php, twitter

Is there any simple/prefab way I can just relay the latest tweet matching a certain regex from a protected account  without having to use a database to keep track?

Would you use something like sleep(60) between checks or just cron it minutely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always get a users latest tweet by calling the [GET /users/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show) method. Keep in mind that for a protected user you will have make authenticated requests and that protected tweets should not be shown to people who don't have permission to see the tweet.

Comment: I'm only looking for my own, not anyone elses - I'm looking for some really simple way without having to really implement the entire oauth thing unfortunately

Comment: If you want to use PHP you can modify this simple script to GET a user instead of posting an update. https://gist.github.com/564882